# How to ask for ratio between more than two items?

Tags: grammar

Me: Did you figure out the recipe?

Person: It's mostly mayo and ketchup with some mustard and sambal for spice.

Me: What is the ratio of mayo to ketchup to mustard to sambal?

If it was only mayo and ketchup I'd say "what's the ratio between mayo and ketchup?" but since it's more than two items I'm not sure.

Comment: What are the proportions of mayo, ketchup, mustard and sambal?

Comment: "*What are the ratios between the ingredients?*"

Answer (score 3):

You can use *ratio* to refer to more than two items. But *proportion* or *relationship* are also possible. Proportions or *parts* are often used in recipes.

> Definition of ratio

1a : the indicated quotient of two mathematical expressions

b : the relationship in quantity, amount, or size between two or more things : PROPORTION

2 : the expression of the relative values of gold and silver as determined by a country's currency laws

MW

Comment: Fine. I'll delete the suggestion. I didn't think it worth a separate answer if you wished to incorporate it into your own, but I may do a little research and add my own now.